# Could not determine the current leader

Tags: mesos, marathon

I'm in this situation in which I got two masters and four slaves in mesos. All of them are running fine. But when I'm trying to access marathon I'm getting the '**Could not determine the current leader**' error. I got marathon in both masters (117 and 115).
This is basically what I'm running to get marathon up:

```
java -jar ./bin/../target/marathon-assembly-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --master 172.16.50.117:5050 --zk zk://172.16.50.115:2181,172.16.50.117:2181/marathon
```

Could anyone shed some light over this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would double-check that you're able to talk to Zookeeper from the Marathon hosts.

Next, there are a few related points to be aware of:

- Per the Zookeeper administrator's guide (http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup) you should have an odd number of Zookeeper instances for HA.  A cluster size of two is almost certainly going to turn out badly.
- For a highly available Mesos cluster, you should run an odd number of masters and also make sure to set the `--quorum` flag appropriately based on that number.   See the details of how to set the `--quorum` flag (and why it's important) in the operational guide on the Apache Mesos website here: http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/operational-guide
- In a highly-available Mesos cluster (#masters > 1) you should let both the Mesos agents and the frameworks discover the leading master using Zookeeper.  This lets them rediscover the leading master in case a failover occurs.  In your case assuming canonical ZK ports you would set the `--zk` flag on the Mesos masters to `--zk=zk://172.16.50.117:2181,172.16.50.115:2181/mesos` (add a third ZK instance, see the first point above).  The same value should be used for the `--master` flags in both the Mesos agents and Marathon, instead of specifying a single master.

Comment: Was exactly this... wrong configuration on zookeeper. I was basically assigning the same server_id to both servers.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to run an odd number of masters in your cluster. To do so, either add another master so you have three or remove one so you have only one.